# Waking up iPhone causes the alarm's volume to reduce after a few seconds

Tags: iphone, ios, alarm

I'm using iPhone 12 with iOS 15.2, and I have set alarms with custom ringtones from the music library which is synced from my laptop (macOS 12). When the alarm is triggered and the ringtone starts playing, if I tap the screen to wake up the iPhone, the ringtone's volume reduces after a few seconds. If I leave it alone, the alarm will altogether stop after 15 (or is it 30?) minutes. These behaviors are 100% reliable.

How can I modify these default behaviors? I.e. How can I set the reduction of volume and the timeout of alarms?